# Linked-List C++,

Tags: c++, arrays, graph, linked-list

The input is in the following format

```
5
1 2  9.0
1 3 12.0
2 4 18.0
2 3  6.0
2 5 20.0
3 5 15.0
0
1 5
```

The first number is the number of vertexes in the graph. Then next lines up to 0 are the edges of the graph. With the first and second numbers being the vertexes and the third being how far the edge is between them. Trying to read in the data and store the edges into there locations in the List adjacency for that vertex. This example would make a graph with five vertexes with edges from 1 to 2&3. 2 to 4&3&1 etc. I do not know if the format for storing into the list in my `readIn` function is correct (`myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency -> vertex=p2;`) .

Is `myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency -> vertex=p2;` the correct way to store it? Ff not how I would store the info into the adjacency lists for each vertex? Also I am getting a Segmentation fault after entering four numbers.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

struct ListCell
{
   ListCell* next;
   int vertex;
   double weight;

   ListCell(int v, double w, ListCell* nxt)
   {
      vertex = v;
      weight = w;
      next = nxt;
   }
};

typedef ListCell* List;

struct Vertex
{
   bool signaled;
   long distance;
   List adjacency;    
};

struct Graph
{
   int     numVertices;
   Vertex* vertexInfo;

   Graph(int n)
   {
      numVertices = n;
      vertexInfo  = new Vertex[n+1];
      for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      {
         vertexInfo[i].signaled = false;
      }
   }
};

//==============================================================
//                   readIn
//==============================================================
// 
//==============================================================

void readIn()
{
   int g;
   int p1;
   int p2;
   float edge;
   scanf("%i ", &g);

   Graph myGraph(g);
   scanf("%i", &p1);
   while(p1 != 0)
   {
      scanf("%i", &p2);
      scanf("%f", &edge);         
      myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency -> vertex=p2; 
      myGraph.vertexInfo[p2].adjacency -> vertex=p1;
      myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency -> weight=edge; 
      myGraph.vertexInfo[p2].adjacency -> weight=edge;
      scanf("%i", &p1);
   }
}
//==============================================================
//                   main
//==============================================================

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   readIn();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your entire class stuck on this problem? I've seen it on stack overflow at least three times in the past few days. The errors you've posted should be pretty simple to understand and fix.

Comment: Quite a few are. We only covered Linked-List for a day or two. Then our regular teacher left on leave for a month so we have a fill-in.

Comment: You're not declaring a Graph variable here `Graph(g)`. Try `Graph gr(g)`;

Comment: Would `myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency -> vertex=p2;` work for storing the information into the adjacency list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to initialize a graph with `g` as an argument to the constructor but you have something confused -

`Graph(g);`

should be

`Graph myGraph(g);`

Comment: Check your declaration

Comment: Check my comment above.

Comment: So to store in the linked-list associated with each vertex of the graph would I do `myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency -> vertex=p2;` while reading it in? It complies that way but that doesn't mean it is right.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
void readIn()
{
   int g;

   ...

   Graph(g);
```

The compiler doesn't like it that you first said "`g` is an `int`" and then said "`g` is a graph".

Answer (score -1):

You should place the readIn function **inside** your Graph struct so it can acces its members. And also you can use

```
Graph graph(g);
```

instead of

```
Graph(g);
```